# Remove words from a text file with Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using iOS MapKit in Swift. I obtain a tableview of a routes directions. I then save these into a text file (Roads.txt). Once in the text file I want to strip off everything but the roads name. This means I want to strip off words like "North", "Turn", "Right" etc. Is there a way to do this in Swift, or must I save the file to a database and process the change there?

My code, which works, is as follows:

```
// Assign variables
let steps = directionsArray[indexPath.section].route.steps
let step = steps[indexPath.row] 
let instructions = step.instructions
let distance = step.distance.kilometers()

// Save Directions to text file
let directions = ["\(instructions) - \(distance),"]
let filePath = getDocumentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("Roads.txt")
let directionstext = directions.joinWithSeparator("\n")
do {
   try directionstext.writeToFile(filePath, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
} catch {
 print ("Error it did not write to file")
}

//read directions from text file

let file = "Roads.txt" // read from this file
if let dir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true).first {
    let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: dir).URLByAppendingPathComponent(file)
do {
    let Direc = try NSString(contentsOfURL: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print(Direc)
}
catch {print("failed to find file")}
}
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of what the content of your output file currently looks like? Also, what do you want as a final result? Do you just need one file that only contains road names or do you also need the version with all the directions?

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for replying!! the current text file looks like the following    Proceed to Infinite Loop - 0.00,
Turn right onto N De Anza Blvd - 0.08,
Turn right to merge onto I-280 S - 0.12,
Take exit 3A to merge onto CA-87 - 7.81,
Keep right to merge onto Guadalupe Parkway S - 0.25,
Keep left to merge onto CA-87 S - 0.85, I would like it to look like  Infinite Loop - 0.00,
N De Anza Blvd - 0.08,
I-280 S - 0.12,
CA-87 - 7.81,
Guadalupe Parkway S - 0.25,
CA-87 S - 0.85, kind regards Jonathan

Comment: So what you are looking for is a way to split the instructions property of each step to isolate the road name. Unfortunately, that will not be easy because there is no definitive rule for what needs to be removed. If you try to do it by searching for words like 'Turn' or 'onto' then it would get tripped up by road names like 'Turner Street' or 'Toronto Boulevard' and the existence of instructions like 'Take exit 3A to merge onto...' mean that there could be a huge number of potential instructions for all the different exits. Is there any way to get an exhaustive list of possible instructions?

Comment: At the moment I am just preparing a "proof of concept" app. So I don't need an exhaustive list. just a couple of "cleaning" routines so I can demonstrate the overall concept of charging an insurance rate based on the time an insured spends on any one road. If you could help with a few  commands I can incorporate this into this version of the app. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, based on the above info, I reckon there are two possible routes to take with this (pun intended)...

**Option 1:** Configure the 'back end' or the source of the information so that it delivers the instructions in two halves - direction and street - that way you can just discard the bit that you don't need when creating your required file. This would be simple and tidy, but may or may not be possible.

**Option 2:** Filter the file to remove the unwanted info.
For the sake of demonstrating the theory, let's assume that there are only two possible instructions: "Turn left onto" and "Turn right onto". You can then strip all of the instructions out of the file with the following code:

```
let possibleInstructions = ["Turn left onto ", "Turn right onto "]
for instruction in possibleInstructions {
    direc = direc.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(instruction, withString: "")
}
```

Where `direc` is the file that you are reading in and `possibleInstructions` is an array of all the possible instructions that might occur in that file. So for instance, this would take:

*Turn left onto Infinite Loop - 0.00, Turn right onto N De Anza Blvd - 0.08, Turn left onto I-280 S - 0.12, Turn right onto  CA-87 - 7.81, Turn right onto Guadalupe Parkway S - 0.25, Turn left onto onto CA-87 S - 0.85*

and return:

*Infinite Loop - 0.00, N De Anza Blvd - 0.08, I-280 S - 0.12,  CA-87 - 7.81, Guadalupe Parkway S - 0.25, onto CA-87 S - 0.85*

Obviously, the list of possible instructions would be much longer than this and you would need extra code to handle special cases such as "Take exit X to merge onto ", but it sounds like that might be a challenge for later in the process.

Comment: I just want to say thank you for all of the responses. It really helped and works

Comment: Great stuff, don't forget to accept the answer if it worked for you, cheers.

Comment: With pleasure - how do I do that?

Comment: Can I be very cheeky - if you have a few moments could you help me with my next (and last) question  "struggling to connect to and select an sqlite table in swift"
http://stackoverflow.com/q/39350127/6619099?sem=2